# Substring after last space

Tags: sql-server

I have a string where i need to extract the number before characters gsm

EG. 250 in 'Galerie Silk WHITE 250gsm SRA1 (4250 BP)'

i am using the below to find the position of gsm however now i need to only return numbers after the last space

Any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT 
CHARINDEX('gsm', 'Galerie Silk WHITE 250gsm SRA1 (4250 BP)') 
,left('Galerie Silk WHITE 250gsm SRA1 (4250 BP)',(CHARINDEX('gsm', 'Galerie Silk WHITE 250gsm SRA1 (4250 BP)')-1)  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use REVERSE

```
DECLARE @value nvarchar(MAX) = 'Galerie Silk WHITE 250gsm SRA1 (4250 BP)'
SET @value = left(@value,(CHARINDEX('gsm', @value)-1)  )
SELECT @Value
SET @value = RIGHT(@Value,CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@value)))
SELECT @value
```